# delimiter [0001] in a text file, reading using np.loadtxt in python

Tags: python, arrays, file-io, input, numpy

I have a text file with several rows.
An example of a row is :
3578312 10 3 7 8

However the delimiter is [0001] (in a box) instead of traditional delimiters like comma or a tab etc.

I'm using numpy in python to read this, does anyone know what the delimiter should be?
I've searched the documentation but haven't got anything.

```
import numpy as np
read_data= np.genfromtxt(fname, delimiter='\u0001')
```

Gives:

```
array([ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan])
```

But when I physically convert the null delimiter to a comma delimiter, I can read it with the proper values.

Comment: First, if you're in Python 2.x, normal strings don't handle `\u` escapes, so that's just 6 regular characters; you probably want `u'\u0001'` or `'\x01'`.

Comment: Second, what makes you think `\u0001` is the right want to match whatever you mean by "[0001] (in a box)"? And then you call it "the null delimiter", which is even more confusing. What are you _actually_ trying to match here? NUL, ctrl-A, some weird sequence of characters, …? Without knowing the bytes that are actually in your file, nobody can tell you how to read it.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the text you're trying to parse and the expected output? What you have so far is really confusing.

Comment: @abarnert : The text file is generated from a Hive query which I don't have access to. I know that \u0001 is not the right delimiter. It was just a hypothetical example. I am unable to paste delimiter here, it looks like a closed square box with 0001 in a 2 row by 2 column fashion.

Comment: @Vedant what text editor are you opening this file with?  That sounds like a unsupported unicode character placeholder that I've seen some browsers use.  It could be anything.

Comment: @roippi Thanks for understanding my problem. I am using Gedit (Ubuntu), should I try some other specific editor to figure it out?

Comment: @Vedant give us the `print(repr(open('your_file', 'rb').read(100)))`

Comment: @Vedant Also how do you physically convert null delimiters to comma delimiters?

Comment: @Vedant try: `np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter='0001')`, and it would be nice to specify what what `0001` in a box means... if it is `[0001]` you can also just do `np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter='[0001]')`

Comment: Hi Viktor, I physically converted the unkown delimiter to a comma by doing a replace all in Gedi, and by copy-pasting the delimiter. Thank you for the hint: print(repr(open('your_file', 'rb').read(100)))                                                   I got this:                                                                    '3578299\x0116\x011\x010\x010\x010\x010\x010\n3578312\x0110\x013\x010\x010\x010\x010\x010\n3578312\x0112\x018\x010\x010\x010\x015\x010\n3578312\x0114\x014\x010\x010\x010\x010\x010\n3578312\x01'

Comment: Thank you all for solving my problem and all the extra information.

Comment: @Vedant: Have you read the [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) in the docs? It explains a lot of this much better than we (well, at least I) could ever hope to in the SO format.

Comment: @abarnert: Doing that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that \u0001 is not the right delimiter. It was just a hypothetical example. I am unable to paste delimiter here, it looks like a closed square box with 0001 in a 2 row by 2 column fashion.

Most likely, `\u0001` *is* the right delimiter in a sense, you're just doing it wrong.

There are fonts that use symbols like that for displaying non-printing control characters, so that 0001-in-a-box is the representation of U+0001, aka Start of Heading, aka control-A.*

The first problem is that the Python 2.x literal `'\u0001'` doesn't specify that character. You can't use `\u` escapes in `str` literals, only `unicode` literals. [The docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) explain this, but it makes sense if you think about it. So, the literal `'\u0001'` isn't the character U+0001 in your source file's encoding, it's six separate characters (a backslash, a letter, and four numbers).

So, could you just use `u'\u0001'`? Well, yes, but then you'd need to decode the text file to Unicode, which is probably not appropriate here. It isn't really a text file at all, it's a binary file. And the key is to look at it that way.

Your text editor can't do that, because it's… well, a *text* editor, so it decodes your binary file as if it were ASCII (or maybe UTF-8, Latin-1, cp1252, whatever) text, then displays the resulting Unicode, which is why you're seeing your font's representation of U+0001. But Python lets you deal with binary data directly; that's what a `str` does.

So, what are the actual bytes in the file? If you do this:

```
b = f.readline()
print repr(b)
```

You'll probably see something like this:

```
'357812\x0110\x0113\x017\x018\n'
```

And that's the key: the actual delimiter you want is `'\x01'`.**

---

Of course you *could* use `u'\u0001'.encode('Latin-1')`, or whatever encoding your source file is in… but that's just silly. You know what byte you want to match, why try to come up with an expression that represents that byte instead of just specifying it?

---

If you wanted to, you could also just convert the control-A delimiters into something more traditional like a comma:

```
lines = (line.replace('\x01', ',') for line in file)
```

But there's no reason to go through the extra effort to deal with that. Especially if some of the columns may contain text, which may contain commas… then you'd have to do something like prepend a backslash to every original comma that's not inside quotes, or quote every string column, or whatever, before you can replace the delimiters with commas.

---

*  Technically, it should be shown as a non-composing non-spacing mark… but there are many contexts where you want to see invisible characters, especially control characters, so many fonts have symbols for them, and many text editors display those symbols as if they were normal spacing glyphs. Besides 0001 in a box, common representations include SOH (for "Start of Heading") or A (for "control-A") or 001 (the octal code for the ASCII control character) in different kinds of boxes. [This page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0001/fontsupport.htm) and [this](http://codepoints.net/U+0001) show how a few fonts display it.

** If you knew enough, you could have easily deduced that, because `'\x01'` in almost any charset will decode to `u'\u0001'`. But it's more important to know how to look at the bytes directly than to learn other people's guesses…

Comment: Thank you @abarnert for all the knowledge and solving my problem.